# Custom HTML tag: JS compile error for userType dataLayer push

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager

I've been trying to adapt an existing (& working tag) to be a little more efficient/elegant if you will.

So the situation is, that we have a method of pushing the userType into the dataLayer via GTM Custom HTML tag. However, I've been coming up against compile error when trying to publish the tag.

Here's the the tag:

```
<script>
(function() {
var ipaddress;;
var type = 'external';
try {
  jQuery.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    ipaddress = data.ip;
    var internal = [
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address"
    ];
    var userType = internal.indexOf(ipaddress) == -1 ? ‘external’ : ‘internal’;
    }
    if (ipaddress) {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'ipResolved',
        ipaddress: ipaddress,
        userType: userType
      });
    }
  });
} catch(e) {
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'ipResolved',
    ipaddress: 'N/A',
    iplocation: 'N/A'
  });
 }
})();
</script>
```

Can anyone shed some light on where I'm going wrong? I think I'm too close to it so I can't see the obvious.

Comment: At the line thats start with usertype the words internal and external are wrapped in ‘smart’ quotes. Use straight ones instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS had some minor mistakes:

- Wrong quotes. It was `‘` instead `'`
- One unnecessary `}`

. Working version is here:

```
(function() {
var ipaddress;
var type = 'external';
try {
  jQuery.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    ipaddress = data.ip;
    var internal = [
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address",
      "IP address"
    ];
    var userType = internal.indexOf(ipaddress) == -1 ? 'external' : 'internal';

    if (ipaddress) {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'ipResolved',
        ipaddress: ipaddress,
        userType: userType
      });
    }
  });
} catch(e) {
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'ipResolved',
    ipaddress: 'N/A',
    iplocation: 'N/A'
  });
 }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you Victor, it worked like a charm. You're a gentleman!